# Specifying TextOptions at Control level for clearer fonts

Tags: silverlight, xaml, text, fonts, silverlight-5.0

So I'm trying to take advantage of all the `TextOptions` introduced in SL5 (`TextRenderingMode`, `TextHintingMode`, `TextFormattingMode`) and get a nice uniform (performance minded) Segeo UI font throughout an app.

My problem lies in the fact that these don't seem to be getting inherited through all the controls. I set them as resources like;

```
<TextFormattingMode x:Key="THETextFormattingMode">Display</TextFormattingMode>
<TextHintingMode x:Key="THETextHintingMode">Fixed</TextHintingMode>
<TextRenderingMode x:Key="THETextRenderingMode">Auto</TextRenderingMode>
```

Then I have them set as setters on individual controls like `TextBlock` and `TextBox` like;

```
<Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="{StaticResource THETextFormattingMode}" />
<Setter Property="TextOptions.TextHintingMode" Value="{StaticResource THETextHintingMode}" />
<Setter Property="TextOptions.TextRenderingMode" Value="{StaticResource THETextRenderingMode}" />
```

Except I'm seeing discrepancies between the controls still, example image below with "tt" taken as a screen shot from the same screen. The "tt" on the left is from a `TextBox` and the one on the right is from a `TextBlock` which both have the `TextOptions.*Mode` set the same.

[image]

What am I missing here? Why are they not identical? The text from the `TextBlock` ("tt" image on the right) appears sharper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe different default colors in `TextBlock` and `TextBox` for `Foreground` and `Background` result in this effect when combined/overlapping.

Have you tried to set them both to Foreground="#FFFFFF" and Background="#000000"?

Comment: Hmm, I'll give that a shot and see the results. They all point to the same staticresource foreground color, but the background on the TextBlock in the example was a very light gray. I do still the same effect however elsewhere where everything is black on white, but I will try the inverted color scheme and see what it results.